# With browsers that have full-page zoom, can I use the feature to set zoom for iframes?

Tags: html, iframe, zooming

I think every browser has user-controllered full-page zoom nowadays. Is it in anyway accessible to developers, via either html, css or javascript?

I'd like to provide an iframe, or even a normal frame, and set it to, say, 50% zoom. (Relative to the current zoom of the containing document, ideally.)

Is it at all doable? I don't mind if it's an HTML 5 solution as long as it has an existing functional implementation. Even if it's in a nightly build.

I'd be very happy if it worked with at least WebKit and Gecko, and bonus if Trident too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works in Safari 4.0.2 and latest WebKit nightly. It doesn't work in Google Chrome (neither Windows nor Mac), however.

As for Firefox 3.5 and IE 8.0, no deal. Also, no deal on latest Camino nightly.

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
  iframe {
    width  : 500px;
    height : 250px;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function setZoom(element, zoom) {
    element.style.zoom = (zoom || 50) + '%'
  }
</script>

<p>Hello World</p>

<iframe 
  src    = 'http://google.com' 
  onload = "setZoom(this.contentDocument.body)"
  />
```

Comment: This is the solution I offered, only implemented with javascript rather than css-syntax...

Comment: Well, not really, because you didn't offer anything regarding iframes, and setting zoom directly on the iframe element (css: iframe { zoom: 0.5 }) doesn't work. So I had to sneak inside the iframe's content document after it loaded to set its css after the fact.

Comment: The iframe tag has nothing to zoom, which is why I didn't suggest applying it to the iframe tag.

Comment: You sure you read the question? See that part where I say "set zoom for iframes"? Well. That.

Answer (score 3):

This HTML5 and CSS3 codes working for me are: zoom for IE 6 to 8, and transform scale for the rest of the modern browsers.

```
#iframe{
    zoom: 0.75;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.75);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0; }
```

Firefox 3.5 and up, Safari 3.1, Chrome 4.0, Opera 10.5 are supported.

Looking for a JS or JQuery solution like [this](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingZoomer/) which works cross browser for old versions with custom built functions based on xy axis and offset.

I believe the path is to use xy axis functions but can´t find any pre-made zoom-out code to take it as a seed.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I can think of is [`Zoom`](http://www.css3.com/css-zoom/) in CSS3:

```
div.zoom { zoom: 200%; }

<div class="zoom">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

This *will not* work merely by adding it to an ifarme tag:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" class="zoom" /> <!-- doesn't work -->
```

You'll have to apply it to a content-tag within the iframe DOM itself, either the BODY or a wrapper-div.

Other than that, I don't know of a way to do this that would find great support cross-browser.

Comment: Does any browser implement this zoom property yet?

Comment: Your example works in Safari 4, doesn't FF 3.5. However, setting zoom on iframes has no effect.

Comment: As stated in the answer, even though CSS3 has this feature, it is not well-supported, and as such shouldn't be implemented...yet :)

Comment: Well, thanks for the pointer to zoom. I was able to come up with the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

That can also be done in FF, like this:

```
iframe {
 -moz-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5); /* 50% */
}
```

It works great!

Check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform