# How to have different viewport width, scalable meta values in one page?

Tags: html, iframe, viewport, meta

I'm wondering if having two different viewport meta values are possible in one page through embedded iframe technique?

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>
        <div>
                Content 1
        </div>
        <div style="width: 300px;">
                <iframe style="width: 300px; height: 100px; overflow: scroll;" src="iframe.html"></iframe>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**iframe.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1000, initial-scale=0.5, user-scalable=yes">
</head>
<body>
        <div style="height: 100px; background-color: #0ff;">
                Content 2
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't get viewport meta values like width or user-scalable working inside iframe.
It's just ignored.
Is there a workaround? Basically I'm trying to achieve so user can zoom the iframe content while user can't zoom the outside area.

Comment: possible duplicate of [With browsers that have full-page zoom, can I use the feature to set zoom for iframes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309498/with-browsers-that-have-full-page-zoom-can-i-use-the-feature-to-set-zoom-for-if)